# Java: How many objects are created in the code?

Tags: java, object

How many objects are created in the following code?

```
String a, b, c;
a = "1234";
b = a;
c = a + b;
```

I was been told the answer is `2`, because only a and b point to their own data.

`c` is only created from using `a` and `b`. However, isn't the act of declaring a variable considered **creating** it? Is this question vague? I said `3`.

Comment: If I do `String a;`, where's the object? What if I do `String a = null;`?

Comment: 2 object it seems, a="1234" and a+B

Comment: @Aamir String is an object in java

Comment: *"However, isn't the act of declaring a variable considered creating it?"* Yes, you create the **variable**, not the object.

Comment: Also question is not specific enough. Do you mind on how the + operator is implemented? If it uses StringBuilder, then StringBuilder itself might also create more objects, and those in turn might create more. Where do you want to stop?

Comment: you can tell your teacher the question is vague, because + operator may create two objects (1- StringBuilder, 2- String)

Comment: Also, the "1234" String might be interned, so you could even ask if it qualifies as "creating" an object ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a = "abcd"` creates a `String` object, and initializes it with the value "abcd". So that's one object

`b = a` makes `b` point to the same spot as `a`, so then `a + b` will create a new object, which is then assigned to `c`. That makes a total of two objects created

Comment: I do believe this is what the teacher was looking for. Students aren't meant to know at this stage that `+` _can_ be implemented with `StringBuilder`s or that a `String` is backed by a `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is 2. when b=a, in fact, a has a reference to b. when you debug your program on your eclipse, you will see a and b have a same id. They are one Object actually.

Comment: as @FlorentBayle have already mentioned. a + b creates another object of type StringBuilder